# Require password only when changing password devise registration

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

I have a registration/edit form that is rendered through a `Devise::RegistrationsController` within my application. The way it works now you must provide your current password when making any updates to the form. They way I want it to work is that the `current_password`is only required when you are updating the `password` field... or you must repeat the "new_password" as a means of confirmation. I have done some reading on the Devise Wiki, mainly the following links and they don't seem to list a solution for this. If anyone has some insight on how this might be achieved I would appreciate it.

https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Allow-users-to-edit-their-password

https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Allow-users-to-edit-their-account-without-providing-a-password

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So I've been digging on trying to solve this I have found the solution.

In my model (user.rb) I added `:validatable` to the following snippet of code:

```
  devise :omniauthable, :database_authenticatable, :registerable, :recoverable, :rememberable, :validatable,
     :confirmable, :trackable, reset_password_keys:[:email, :company_id],
     request_keys: [:host, :params], omniauth_providers: [:auth0]
```

Then in my registration controller, I added the following:

```
def update_resource(resource, params)
  if !params[:password].blank?
    resource.password = params[:password]
    resource.password_confirmation = params[:password_confirmation]
  end

  resource.update_without_password(params)
end
```

And finally in my application controller, I added `:password_confirmation` to the following snippet:

```
devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit(:account_update) do |u|
  u.permit(:first_name, :last_name, :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :phone_number, :receive_emails,
           location_attributes: [:id, :street, :city, :state, :zip, :country])
end
```

With this combination, once the form gets submitted it will fall into the `update_resource` block that I have overwritten. It will check to make sure that `resource.password` and `password_confirmation` are the same. On top of that now that `current_password` is out of the equation, you no longer have to enter your password everytime to save changes.

Answer (score 2):

What you can do is to validate at the time that the user do the update to its account, through the params `params[:user][:password]` and `params[:user][:password_confirmation]`:

This way if there are no `password` nor `password_confirmation` then use the `update_without_password` method passing the `user_params`, the other way do it just using the `update_attributes` method

```
  def update
    ...
    if params[:user][:password].blank? && params[:user][:password_confirmation].blank?
      if @user.update_without_password(user_params)
        flash[:notice] = 'User updated successfully'
        redirect_to some_path
      else
        render :edit
      end
    else
      if @user.update_attributes(user_params)
        # login before update passing the current user
        sign_in(User.find(current_user.id), :bypass => true) 
        flash[:notice] = 'User updated successfully'
        redirect_to some_path
      else
        render :edit
      end
    end
    ...
  end
```

Comment: I appreciate your help, this ended up not working for me. I ended up posting the solution that I found

Answer (score 2):

Create a registration controller in app/controllers/registrations_controller.rb

```
class RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController

  protected

  def update_resource(resource, params)
    # Require current password if user is trying to change password.
    return super if params["password"]&.present?

    # Allows user to update registration information without password.
    resource.update_without_password(params.except("current_password"))
  end
end
```

Comment: Perfect and most beautiful solution.